# Complexity and hardness of undirected path

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

Let $PATH = \{(G,s,t) \mid \exists \text{path from}~s\text{ to }t\text{ in }G\}$, where $G$ is a directed graph. We know that $PATH$ is $NL$ complete. I am wondering what the complexity class of $PATH$ on undirected graphs is and whether any hardness results for $PATH$ on undirected graphs are known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undirected version of PATH, usually known as USTCON, is in L due to [Reingold's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL_(complexity)).

USTCON is trivially complete for L with respect to logspace reductions. I don't know if it is L-complete with respect to weaker reductions such as $\mathsf{AC}^0$ reductions; see [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85251/natural-logspace-complete-problems).